# Launch nikto scanner. 'No web server found'

Tags: perl, security, cmd

---

Launching nikto scanner:

```
perl ./nikto.pl -h http://myserver_ip:port/
```

Message:

```
- Nikto v2.1.5
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ No web server found on myserver_ip:port
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ 0 host(s) tested
```

But web application http://myserver_ip:port/ works fine through browser

What am I doing wrong?

using:

- Strawberry Perl 5.22.0.1-32bit;
- Nikto v2.1.5

Comment: I know its old .. but perhaps someone else getting here .. are you sure its "myserver_IP:port" that is showing up on the "no web server found"? I'm in the same boat, and its not parsing the CLI properly, the *time* is showing up where the IP is, and the IP is showing up where the port is.  You may find additional information by putting a "-D d" at the end (without the quotes)  -D d is for debugging, and you may see something in the first block that explains what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
perl ./nikto.pl -h http://myserver_ip:port/
```

Need to run:

```
nikto.bat -h http://myserver_ip:port/
```

from the directory with nikto